# why context is undefined in svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

I'm working on a component and i need to use context for it. But i don't know why when i using getContext, It's undefined.

This is a part of my codes on first component (Index Component):

```
import { setContext } from 'svelte';
import {onMount} from "svelte";

let tempSuggest;

const suggestModel = {
   category_id: 1,
   title: "",
   images: [{}],
   catalogues: [{}],
   dependent_attributes: [{}],
   independent_attributes: [{}],
};

$: tempSuggest = Object.assign({}, suggestModel);

onMount(() => {
   setContext(clientProductSuggest, tempSuggest);
});
```

In html codes of first component (loading sub components in the end of index file):

```
<svelte:component this={component} {...props}/>
```

In second component:

```
import { getContext } from 'svelte';
const c = getContext('clientProductSuggest');

console.log(c);
```

And now context is undefined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not probably not going to cover this question but keep in mind that `getContext` is only gonna work for **children** of the `setContext` component.

For cross-component sharing we should use stores.

I am writing this answer because if I had found it here, it would have saved me a few hours of research and posting to the svelte community chat.

Answer (score 1):

This is because *contexts* in Svelte are not reactive by default, when you assign `tempSuggests` to the context it is in fact *undefined*

In order to get reactivity in your context you should create `tempSuggests` as a store:

```js
import { setContext } from 'svelte';
import { writable } from "svelte/store";

let tempSuggest = writable({});

const suggestModel = {
   category_id: 1,
   title: "",
   images: [{}],
   catalogues: [{}],
   dependent_attributes: [{}],
   independent_attributes: [{}],
};

$: tempSuggest.update(value => Object.assign(value, suggestModel));
setContext('clientProductSuggest', tempSuggest);
```

Also consider the following:

- `setContext` does not have to be called inside *onMount*
- the first argument of `setContext` should be a string (I added '')
- `suggestModel` is now a store and should be treated as such in the children

Comment: I have used your code, But why when i log the context in console after setContext, In get method doesn't show to me the suggestModel?

Comment: I wanna to make my temporary variable empty and looklike as suggestModel, when pages load or when user presses the cancel button, then context needs to be updated.

Comment: When you say "log the context after setContext" is that in the child, immediately after doing getContext ? Because at that point you have not updated the tempSuggest yet

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make it a store to make it have the right value but in fact that's just working around the initial problem :

I don't know why but reactive statements/blocks are executed only at the end of component initilization. So the real order of execution is :

```js
import { setContext } from 'svelte';
import {onMount} from "svelte";

let tempSuggest;

const suggestModel = {
   category_id: 1,
   title: "",
   images: [{}],
   catalogues: [{}],
   dependent_attributes: [{}],
   independent_attributes: [{}],
};

setContext("clientProductSuggest", tempSuggest);

$: tempSuggest = Object.assign({}, suggestModel);
```

... and now it makes sense.

I have no idea why this is the case. Bute [here](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-3-$-marks-a-statement-as-reactive) the docs indeed state :
`Reactive statements run after other script code and before the component markup is rendered`

If you want to play around:
https://svelte.dev/repl/6ba4692567754a8f8e3499a3ed38edf3?version=3.59.1